# cdef an array in cython that changes size in a loop, are there memory issues?

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, cython

I understand that in cython i cannot cdef an array inside a loop, i must do so before the loop. What happens if inside the loop i set the array i've initialized outside the loop to be vastly different sizes at each iteration?

Imagine something like this:

```
cdef int i
cdef int [:] A
for i in range(100): 
    A = np.zeros(np.random.randint(10, 1000), dtype=np.int32)
```

The size of `A` will vary greatly from iteration to iteration. Could this lead to any kind of memory issues? Could someone explain what is going on exactly in memory as i go through the loop? If this is problematic are there any alternatives? Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest putting this loop in the calling Python code, and calling the Cython function with the 2d `A` array.  Focus on gaining speed when processing `A`.  Creating `A` like this does not take advantage of Cython's compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No issues - memoryviews are reference counted like normal Python objects so when the new array is assigned to `A` the old one's reference count drops to 0 and it's freed.

The only exception to this is where you create the memoryviews from a pointer rather than a Python object, in which case you have to handle the memory. That doesn't apply here though.

(As @hpaulj says in a comment, this won't get any speedup from Cython but I assume your real code does a bit more work in the loop)